# A FOR loop in an arbitrary SELECT statement

Tags: postgresql

What's wrong with these statements.

It keeps telling me 'ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FOR"'

```
BEGIN
FOR foo in select id from tbl_number where error_msg = 'FAIL' and log_time::date between '2014-05-31' and '2014-05-31'
    LOOP
        select * from tbl_number 
        where id = foo.id
        order by log_time desc limit 1;
    END LOOP;
END
```

Comment: It needs to be in a `DO $$ ... $$` block. Keep in mind that `DO` blocks don't return anything...

Comment: Check my answer with the correction suggested by @vyegorov

Comment: Any time you think "I need a loop" when working with SQL, it's generally a sign that you're not thinking "relationally" enough: think in terms of combining sets of data according to certain rules, not acting on one bit of data then the next.

Comment: As NickBarnes says, the actual error is because you can't just write procedural code like loops on their own in Postgres, they have to be in a function or (with certain limitations) a `DO` block.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need that loop

```
select distinct on (id) *
from tbl_number 
where
    error_msg = 'FAIL'
    and
    log_time::date between '2014-05-31' and '2014-05-31'
order by id, log_time desc;
```

Comment: You mean `DISTINCT ON`?